# How to get a string from a dictionary and use it as a named parameter in any function?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, named-parameters

I have a dictionary in python,

```
mapper = {'my_func': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

I want to call a function which takes a, b, c, d and e parameters -

```
functn(a, b, c, d, e=None)
```

The parameters a, b, c, d is what I want to use while calling the function, and not e, and those parameter names are defined in that dictionary.

How can I parse the dictionary values and use them as named parameters in the function, while passing some values to each one of them?

Eg:

I can get named parameter a, by doing this -

```
mapper['my_func'][0]
```

But how to use that value as a named parameter in the above function?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of steps:

```
mapper = {'my_func': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

def functn(v, w, x, y, z):
    return v + w + x + y + z

# create dictionary of arguments to values
d = {**dict(zip(list('vwxy'), mapper['my_func'])), **{'z': 5}}

# unpack dictionary for use in function
res = functn(**d)  # 15
```